# Как вернуть из БД запись <varchar> в enum

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

Есть какое-то Entity:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Peoples")
    public class People implements Serializable {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GeneratedType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private Profession profession;
    
    стандартные геттеры, сеттеры
}
```

Поле profession представлено енумом:

```
public enum Profession {
    MANAGER,
    COUNTER,
    ENGINEER,
}
```

В таблица БД поле Profession сохраняется как VARCHAR.
Есть несколько записей:

| id | Profession |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | MANAGER |
| 1 | MANAGER |
| 2 | COUNTER |

В @RestController пытаюсь вернуть все записи таблицы без каких-либо условий, через:

```
@Autowired
private PageingAndSortingRepository<People, Long> peopleRepository;

    @GetMapping
    public List<People> getAllPeople() {
    return peopleRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(0, 3, Sort.by("id"))).toList();
    }
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: For input string: "MANAGER"; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "MANAGER"
```

Данные должны передаться в теле ответа в JSON виде:

```
{
"id":[Long]
"profession":[Profession]
}
```

Какие только сеттеры и геттеры не ставил, енумы пытался переписать со строковыми значениями, конвертеры пытался писать, ничего не выходит. Ни как не могу понять природу этой ошибки и от куда растут ее корни. Буду весьма признателен, если кто поможет.

Comment: Неправильный мапинг - вот откуда.

Comment: Чтобы строку привести к енаму, придется написать парочку условий. Генератор не сможет их написать, он их просто не знает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Использовать аннотацию @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) чтобы отметить способ хранения енума в базе данных.](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-persisting-enums-in-jpa)

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Peoples")
    public class People implements Serializable {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GeneratedType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Profession profession;
    
    стандартные геттеры, сеттеры
}
```